# Can't import a module from another crate - unresolved import

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a crate called `bar`, the structure looks like this

```
src/
├── bar.rs
└── lib.rs
```

My `src/lib.rs` looks like this

```
#![crate_type = "lib"]
#![crate_name = "bar"]
#![feature(ip_addr)]
#[allow(dead_code)]
pub mod bar;
```

My `bar.rs` has

```
pub struct baz {
  // stuff
}

impl baz {
  // stuff
}
```

Now when I try to use this crate in another crate like:

```
extern crate bar;

use bar::baz;

fn main() {
    let cidr = baz::new("Hi");
    println!("{}", cidr.say());
}
```

This fails with

```
error: unresolved import `bar::baz`. There is no `baz` in `bar`
```

Do I need to declare the module somewhere else?

Comment: cf. http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/334434/trouble_with_modules/

Comment: The `lib.rs` says the crate name is "bar", which is probably wrong. It doesn't fit the error message, but maybe the diagnostic is just bad. (Also, how do you compile these crates?)

Comment: @delnan sorry, I misplaced a number of names while trying to remove non open sourced information. Updated the code now, the diagnostics is good. I've been compiling bar by `cargo build` and uploaded it to crates.io,  the test crate pulls in that as a cargo dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important part you are missing is that crates define their own module. That is, your crate `bar` implicitly defines a module called `bar`, but you also have created a module called `bar` *inside that*. Your struct resides within this nested module.

If you change your main to `use bar::bar::baz;` you can progress past this. You will have to decide if that's the structure you want though. Most idiomatic Rust projects would not have the extra `mod` and would flatten it out:

**src/lib.rs**

```
pub struct Baz {
    // stuff
}

impl Baz {
    // stuff
}
```

Unfortunately, your example code cannot compile, as you have invalid struct definitions, and you call methods that don't exist (`new`), so I can't tell you what else it will take to compile.

Also, structs should be `PascalCase`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. `bar::bar::baz` did work, but I decided that it's not how I want it to look. Now when I copied the contents of `bar.rs` to `lib.rs`, I still cant access `baz` as `use bar::baz`, while `bar::bar::baz` works. Shouldn't `bar::baz` work now?

Comment: @AbhishekChanda you copied the contents of `bar.rs` to `lib.rs` directly, without wrapping it in `mod bar { ... }`, correct? If so, and `use bar::bar::baz` still works, then it sounds like you aren't correctly specifying or compiling your dependencies. I assume you are using Cargo?

Comment: yes, using cargo. And yes, my module structure was messed up. Cleaned up, thanks for your help :)